# Why is FragmentPagerAdapter saveState always null?

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I want to save the state of my `FragmentPagerAdapter` so I can reuse it after the orientation of the screen changed. Unfortunately the method saveState returns always `null`. 
My Adapter consists of an `ActionBar` with two `Fragments`.

Here ist my method call

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(FRAGMENT, viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    outState.putParcelable(ADAPTER, fragmentTabAdapter.saveState());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

But the Adapter in outState is always null. I don't understand why. Is there something special I missed about the use of saveState?
Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

this example works if the fragment is not destroyed

```
private int pageID;

@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
pageID = mViewPager.getCurrentItem(); // 1 save
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pageID, false); // 2 load

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution for my problem. I wanted to save the whole adapter, not just the state of my fragment. With this solution, I have my fragments saved, but they aren't attached to the adapter of the new activity.